# create a pd.Series object with the required length

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, series

```
sampleA = pd.concat([orderByUsersA['orders'],pd.Series(0,index=np.arange(visitors[visitors['group']=='A']['visitors'].sum() - len(orderByUsersA['orders'])), name='orders')],axis=0)
```

Hi,
This question is from my class lecture.

My question is while concatenation, in the second argument of series construction what does the (0,) *Zero* represents. I tried the code by removing the zero to check its function and it returned a future warning of...

> DeprecationWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be
> 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype
> explicitly to silence this warning.   """Entry point for launching an
> IPython kernel.

What does argument 0 do and what are other arguments can be given?

Answer (score 3):

I'll simply the part inside of the `np.arange`, but in essence you create a Series with the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.Series(0, index=np.arange(10), name='orders')
```

Creating a Series like this uses a combination of **positional** (`0`) and **named** arguments (`index=np.arange(10)`, `name='orders'`).

If we look at the [Series class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), it is a class with several arguments and all of them have defined defaults:

```
class pandas.Series(data=None, index=None, dtype=None, name=None, copy=False, fastpath=False)
```

So with the way you're creating the object, the `0` is assigned by position to the first expected argument, which is `data`, then by the name of the arguments you specify it determines what `index` and `name` are, and finally it uses the provided defaults for the arguments you didn't specify.

So your object created with

```
pd.Series(0, index=np.arange(10), name='orders')
```

Is equivalent to the completely explicit creation with:

```
pd.Series(data=0, index=np.arange(10), name='orders', dtype=None,
          copy=False, fastpath=False)
```

In general you would not write out all of the defaults and only specify an argument if it diverges from a default, is an argument without a default, or if specifying the default helps to self-document the code.

Answer (score -1):

You can also simply specify `dtype` in the arguments:

```
class pandas.Series(data=None, index=None, dtype=None, name=None, copy=False, fastpath=False)
```

you can specify this way:

```
Ciccio = pd.Series(dtype = 'object')
```

This is the case of a series of strings (you can use 'object' also for mixed values, other valid values are int64 or float64 or bool ...)

Comment: OP asked how to creaete a Series of type `object` *and* with a specified `size`.